# Convert SQL to LINQ with date

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert below sql command to LINQ but confused as what is possibility to convert with same ouput.

```
Select * 
  from [A].[dbo].[SOMETABLE] 
 where lossdate >= dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
   AND lossdate < dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or are you using some other ORM library to do your sql queries. The way to do this is library specific.

Comment: You might want to check out the [EntityFunctions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @juharr, I have checked that but could not able to figure out the solution for my problem.

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

The [`SqlFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) class has methods that translate to sql server functions when used in a query. (If you are using .NET 3.5 use [this version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) bundled with entity framework instead)

Your query would be directly translated to

```
db.SomeTable.Where(x => x.LossDate >= SqlFunctions.DateAdd("m", SqlFunctions.DateDiff("m", "0", SqlFunctions.GetDate()) - 1, 0) && 
                        x.LossDate < SqlFunctions.DateAdd("m", SqlFunctions.DateDiff("m", "0", SqlFunctions.GetDate()), 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, one way to avoid calling those static methods is getting the upper and down dates this way:

```
var end = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month,1);
var start =DateTime.Now.Month==1? new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year-1, 12, 1):
                                  new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month-1, 1);

var query= context.SomeDbSet.Where(e=>e.LossDate>=start && e.LossDate<end);
```